# Java type safety warning

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I'm trying to make an array of vectors like this:

```
Vector<String>[] wordList = new Vector[29];
for (int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
  wordList[i] = new Vector<String>(100);
}
```

But Java warns me that "new Vector[29]" violates type safety. How do I get rid of the the warning?

Update: I've tried:

```
        wordList = new Vector<String>[29];
```

Of course, but this generates the error: Cannot create a generic array of Vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Vector<String>[] wordList = (Vector<String>[])new Vector[29];
```

Comment: warning: unchecked cast from Vector[] to Vector<String>[]

Comment: @Jeremy, Compare your updated code to the code provided in this answer..it doesn't match. DOH!

Comment: you can cheat by `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` :)

Comment: The warning I'm talking about is using your updated code. The code I have is an error.

Comment: I'm starting to think that's the only way to do it... it feels wrong, though. Thanks!

Comment: Add the line `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` right before the block.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a `List` of `List<String>` instead of an array of `Vectors`, like so:

```
List<List<String>> wordList = new Vector<List<String>>();
```

This doesn't generate any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You [can't make that work](http://www.cogs.susx.ac.uk/courses/dats/notes/html/node181.html) as you want.